# What does $ X = A + u U + v V $ mean in definition of triangle?

Tags: definition, triangles

I'm trying to understand what does the [algorithm](http://web.mst.edu/%7Echaman/home/pubs/2015WimoTriangleTrianglePublished.pdf) does and I'm stuck in both 2.1.1 and 3 sections where the algorithm is explained.
Author says:

> The triangles $ \triangle ABC $ and $ \triangle PQR $ are
> $ X = A + u U + v V $ with $ U = B - A $, $ V = C - A $, $ 0 \le u , v $, $ u + v \le 1 $
> $ X = P + s S + t T $ with $ S = Q - P $, $ T = R - P $, $ 0 \le s, t $, $ s + t \le 1 $

1. Why triangles are defined as sum **point + vector * scalar + vector * scalar** and where these scalars (small letters) $u$, $v$, $s$, $t$ come from?
2. Is $X$ just a form of writing common operator to equate the equalities to find common points (intersection(s))?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the concept of [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space), you can use the operation
\begin{align}
& \text{point}\ +\ \text{vector}\ =\ \text{point}\\
& A + \mathbf{v} = B
\end{align}
to define the point $B$ that you can reach starting from $A$ and moving from there following the vector $\mathbf{v},$ and vice versa, the vector needed to go from $A$ to $B$ as
$$
B-A=\mathbf{v}.
$$

So
$$
A+t\mathbf{v},\qquad 0\leq t\leq 1
$$
or equivalently
$$
A+t(B-A),\qquad 0\leq t\leq 1
$$
represents the set of point from $A$ to $B$, with $A$ corresponding to $t=0$ and $B$ corresponding to $t=1$.

In the same manner, given another point $C$, you can represent all point from $A$ to $C$ with
$$
A+s(C-A),\qquad 0\leq s\leq 1.
$$

Now, each point $P$ of the segment from $B$ to $C$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $B-A$ and $C-A$
$$
P-A=t(B-A)+s(C-A)
$$
with positive coefficients $%t, s$ such that $t+s=1,$ so that
$$
P=A+t(B-A)+s(C-A)
$$

Finally, to represent all points of segment from $A$ to $P$, for all $P$ on the segment from $B$ to $C$, i.e to represent all the points of the triangle $ABC$, we can write
$$
P=A+t(B-A)+s(C-A),\quad 0\leq t\leq 1,\ 0\leq s\leq1,\ t+s\leq 1.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Offtop: which software did you use to draw such an accurate image?

Comment: @Herrgott I use Wolfram Mathematica